# Java Validation messages are not thrown when validations fail in depending class coming from JAR file

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, quarkus

I am developing a Quarkus service application let's call it `Project2`, this application depends on `Project1` which has the `Book` class with `Validation Annotations`.

When an invalid JSON is provided then I do not get the invalid message from the `Book` class. However, if I place the `Book` class within `Poject2` directly without any dependency then I get the error messages.

I would like to know how to get the error messages from the Dependency class which are coming from JAR?

Following is my `Project2` which has the `BookService`:

```
import org.project1.com.Book;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/api")
public class BookService {

    @Path("/generateTestData")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void generateTestData(@Valid final Book book){
        System.out.println("After Successful Validation : " + book.toString());
    }
}
```

Following is my `Project1` `Book class`:

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@ToString
public class Book {
    @NotNull(message="Book ID cannot be NULL")
    @Min(value = 1, message="Book ID cannot be less than 1")
    private int bookId;

    @NotNull(message="Author name cannot be NULL")
    private String author;
}
```

When I make a invalid request from `Postman` to `http://localhost:8080/api/generateTestData` then I do not get any validation messages (bookId should be >= 1 to be a valid input):

```
{
    "bookId" : 0,
    "author" : "Batman"
}
```

Can someone please let me know what's wrong here and how can I fix the issue? I have added the following dependency within my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.project1.com</groupId>
            <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-jib</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: do your Project1 and Project2 use the same version of Spring Boot?

Comment: Do we **really** need the `Author` class to reproduce the problem? Can't you simplify your example code while still keeping the error occurring? And is your `BookService` really in `Project1`, or is it a typo?

Comment: @HonzaZidek Thanks a lot for your response. Yes, that was a typo. `BookService` is in `Project2`. I have modified my class as you mentioned to simplify the example. Actually, I am using the `Quarkus` instead of SprintBoot and broth the project have the same dependency in my Project.

Answer (score 0):

I think y need to add this dependency to get your rest endpoint work otherwise y will get an error invalid MediaType from the resteasy library

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

When you add the dependency, Your endpoint function will be called and you will get 400 (Bad request) and the details of the invalid constraints returned in the response.